# Is it normal for AWS CloudWatch alarms metrics to be stuck at some value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have an issue where I've set up an alarm which measures `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` on an SQS-queue. When it reaches `1`, it spins up an EC2 instance, and when it goes to `0` it should trigger AutoScaling group to downscale it. However, even though I have `0` messages on SQS queue, my alarm remains at `1` message with the state `Ok`, it's like it doesn't recognize the change. I know it's an 'approximate number of messages', but this can go on for days with the value of messages 0, and the actual value on alarm as 1. Is there any clue on why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have also observed that Amazon SQS does not send "zero" metrics to Amazon CloudWatch. My personal theory is that this **reduces the amount of 'chatter'** that SQS needs to send to CloudWatch because there must be a huge number of empty queues.

Fortunately, you can cater for this by going to the **Additional Configuration** in the CloudWatch Alarm and setting **Missing data treatment** to **Treat missing data as bad**. This will trigger the alarm in the same manner as if you set it to trigger on a zero value.

[image: CloudWatch Alarm]

When configuration scaling based on SQS queue sizes, remember the golden rule to **Scale-out quickly but scale-in slowly**. That is, turn on resources reasonably quickly to respond to incoming messages but don't be too hasty to scale-in. Set the Alarm to only trigger after a reasonable period of time relative to how long it takes to launch new resources. So, if you are launching EC2 instances and an instance takes 2 minutes to launch, wait at least 5 minutes to scale-in.

Comment: Thanks John, this is a very interesting insight! I'll try this out and let you know if it works